# How to use regex to capture a word after another word, with newline in between

Tags: python, regex

I've been working on a regex expression within Python to try to match on a certain sequence one time after the occurrence of a word. I've been running into two problems: 1) The text I'm trying to search has a variable amount of characters between the word I want to use as the trigger word and the word I actually want to match and 2) the text is multi-line.

In the following example text, I want to match "lag-10:10" and "lag-10:20" but *not* match "lag-10:30":

```
    vprn 5001 name "5001" customer 1 create
        interface "to-VPLS-6663000" create
            sap lag-10:10 create
        interface "to-VPLS-3000500" create
            sap lag-10:20 create
        vpls 3410001 name "XYZBDVLAN1" customer 1 create
            sap lag-10:30 create
```

The result I am looking for is "'lag-10:10', 'lag-10:20'". I also can't just match on those terms alone because any numbers are expected after "lag-", and I only want to capture that group if it comes after the word "interface" (and not, in the example above, after the word "vpls" as in lag-10:30).

With the networking equipment I'm working with, the text between the word "interface" and "lag" can vary. The way I initially came up with to accomplish this is to match the sequence `lag-10:[^ ]*` only one time and only after the occurrence of the word "interface". The problem is... I have no idea how to go about doing that. Everything I've tried captures either too much or not enough text, and is complicated by the fact that "lag" is on a different line than "interface".

Any help would be appreciated, as I am very new at Regex!

Comment: Use a non-greedy quantifier so you get the shortest match instead of the longest match.

Comment: And use the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.` to match newlines.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the exact output you want here.

Comment: There is no [tag:network-programming] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `re.findall` in multiline mode:

```py
inp = """    vprn 5001 name "5001" customer 1 create
    interface "to-VPLS-6663000" create
        sap lag-10:10 create
    interface "to-VPLS-3000500" create
        sap lag-10:20 create
    vpls 3410001 name "XYZBDVLAN1" customer 1 create
        sap lag-10:30 create"""

matches = re.findall(r'^\s+\binterface.*?\n\s+sap (lag-\d{1,2}:\d{2})', inp, flags=re.M)
print(matches)  # ['lag-10:10', 'lag-10:20']
```

The regex pattern used above matches one line which starts with `interface` as the first word, followed by a line containing `sap-` and a hour:minute timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for this! It has definitely set me on the right track. For my example, the string you provided works, however I need to match the `^\s+\binterface.*?\n\s+sap ` part without consuming it, because all I'm looking for is the lag and the numbers (simply matching on the lag and numbers themselves won't work because I only want to find the groups that come after "interface)". When I enclose it like this, it still captures the content: `(?:^\s+\binterface.*?\n\s+sap )`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Snufkin As far as I know, to not consume or to keep out of match you'd use look behind, but regex engines require look behinds to be of fixed length, so you cant use quantifiers like `* or +` inside it & will have to specify fixed length inside `{}`. Since you want lag after interface, the regex has to be modified to have a fixed width like: `"(?<=interface.{25}\n\s{8}sap )(lag-\d{1,2}:\d{2})"`, this will only match lag without consuming anything else. So the regex become rigid and will fail to match anything if contents after 'interface' has different length than whats specified in the `{}`.

Comment: @anotherGatsby I don't see much need for lookarounds here though, as the API for `re.findall` has good support for capture groups.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was responding about how to keep things out of match. Since OP said he was looking to match `lag` without consuming anything before it. Like not consuming interface and other character and matching only lag and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different solutions here that should work as long as the values are always as you specified:

```
import re
text = """    vprn 5001 name "5001" customer 1 create
        interface "to-VPLS-6663000" create
            sap lag-10:10 create
        interface "to-VPLS-3000500" create
            sap lag-10:20 create
        vpls 3410001 name "XYZBDVLAN1" customer 1 create
            sap lag-10:30 create"""

pattern = r'lag-\d{2}:[1-2]0'
result = re.findall(pattern,text,re.MULTILINE)
print(result)


pattern = r'lag-\d{2}:[1-2]\d{1}'
result = re.findall(pattern,text,re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```